# Excel 2 column comparison: duplicate in one column, but unique as pair

Tags: excel, comparison, excel-formula

I'm trying to compare values across two columns (Product and Location) in Excel to highlight duplicates, but I can't figure out the logical test. I'm looking for rows that match three criteria:

1. Product value is duplicate
2. Product value is not blank
3. Duplicate 'Product' values occur with different 'Location' values

<s>(Products with the same value in the same location are assumed to be distinct for a value I don't have, but products with the same name at different locations may be duplicate).</s>
Edit: I want the formula to evaluate to true only if the same Product occurs in more than one Location.

I can figure out the first two conditions by themselves, but can't figure out how to incorporate the third. I've sorted the table so that the duplicate values should appear next to each other, but there are too many to check by eye.

I'm currently using this logical test for conditional formatting using the first two criteria. 'Product' occurs in column C, 'Location' occurs in column I.

```
=AND(C1<>"",COUNTIF($C:$C,C1)>1)
```

Comment: Can the same product exist multiple times in the same "location"?

Comment: I'm slightly confused... Can you elaborate on "Products with the same value in the same location are assumed to be distinct for a value I don't have, but products with the same name at different locations may be duplicate"?

Comment: I apologize for not being clear. I'm using the formula for conditional formatting, and I want to highlight the cells that meet those 3 criteria. I only want to highlight the cell if the same Product occurs in more than one Location.

Comment: Got it! - Adding a solution now....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your criteria, I think what you need would be the `CountIfs` function for the 3rd criteria....

Your final formula would look as follows:

```
=AND($C1<>"",COUNTIF($C:$C,$C1)>1, COUNTIFS($C:$C,$C1,$I:$I,"<>" & $I1)>0)
```

In effect, your third criteria is saying **Count if the product matches C1 AND the Location does NOT equal I1**

Hope that does the trick!

---

**NOTE:**

The more I think about it, the more I'm pretty sure you **do not** need your second criteria... I've been trying to think of an example where your second criteria would affect the result of this final outcome, but can't find one....

Just something to consider....

Comment: I learned something today.  I have never used the COUNTIFS function.  Nice!

Comment: Thanks, John. That makes sense to me, but it's still highlighting duplicates with the same location. Can you walk me though the last logical test in the COUNTIFS function? I know it's supposed to be evaluating whether the cell in the I column is equal to the value in I1, but I don't understand the role the quotation marks and ampersand play.

Comment: Sure - The `"<>" & I1` is another way of saying **DOES NOT EQUAL I1**... Basically you're saying you want to count all products with the same number, but NOT THE SAME LOCATION... This will do that...

Comment: Here we go - Found a link... http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countif-HP005209029.aspx

Comment: And glad I could show you somethign new @GreenWeenie - I love it when that happens on SO!!!

Answer (score 1):

It might be overkill, but how comfortable are you with PivotTables?

Insert a pivot table, and put the "Product" in the row, with the data as the "count" of Location.

Then add a column with a formula similar to:

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("Location", <top left cell of pivottable> ,"Product", <cell that has product you want a count of>)
```

The "Location" and "Product" text would have to match your column titles.

The easiest way to get the forumla right is to type "=" in the cell you want to have the value in, and then click on the pivot table cell that contains the value.  You then replace the static text, with the cell that has the value you want to look up.